# Will any EF-lens fit on a EOS film camera?

Tags: lens, compatibility, canon-ef

I'm not sure if this already has been asked... Also, it's probably a stupid question.

I have a Canon EOS 1000 film camera, which has an EF-mount. I want to use the Canon 50mm f/1.8 II lens, but I'm not sure if this will fit on the body. I'm worried the lens is too new for this old camera.

Can you help me out here?
Thanks!

Comment: The EF 50mm f/1.8 II lens is one of the oldest designs in Canon's currently available lens lineup. An it or any other EF lens will fit your EOS 1000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work.

Any EF lens will mount on any EOS camera - as long as it's not EF-S or EF-M (which the 50mm f/1.8 isn't).

In addition, MP-E and TS-E lenses will also mount and work on any EOS camera.