# Can I use Canon EF lenses on an EOS 600?

Tags: lens, canon, film, canon-ef

Maybe it is a dumb question, but my camera store has a Canon 600 for €25. I have some ef-lenses at home by canon, I'm not sure if I want to invest in the camera if I can't use the lenses. The owner is not sure, so I want to ask: Can I use my new ef lenses (100-400,24-70..) with the EOS 600 or do I need an adapter?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. The question is about using modern EF lenses on a much older EOS 600 film camera. (European version of the EOS 630) I vote to reopen this question

Comment: But this seems like a duplicate: [Will any EF-lens fit on a EOS film camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61102/will-any-ef-lens-fit-on-a-eos-film-camera)

Answer (score 1):

I see two questions here (if by Canon 600 you mean Canon EOS 600D):

1. Are your lens compatible with Canon 600D? If by 100-400 you mean Canon EF 100-400mm, by 24-70 you mean Canon EF 24-70mm/f2.8 or f4 the answer is yes. Canon 600D have EF-S socket which is compatible with EF lens (vise-versa is not true)
2. Canon EOS 600D is released 2011 so it is old camera and you will find some limitations like dynamic range, high ISO, etc. But if you are happy with the specs (especially on this price) it is pretty good camera.

Based on the comment if we talk about EOS 600, film camera and assuming above comments about the lens models, yes, camera have EF socket and lens you mention are compatible.

Comment: I suspect the OP does actually mean EOS 600; $25 would be a _very_ good price for a working 600D.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, I have no information about this model :(

Comment: [It's a small tweak to the EOS 650](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_650#Variants), don't think there's anything particularly notable about it. But it will take EF lenses.